# Discord Custom Emojis Showing Error while giving it a Variable in DISCORD.PY

Tags: discord, discord.py, syntax-error, bots

I am Trying to Create a '**mine**' command which gives you Economical Money
It is working fine and all and I decided to add an Emoji next to the item , **So i decided to give the Variable names for each of the Emojis like so** :

LANGUAGE IS DISCORD.PY

```
#declaring Emoji Variables
sEmoji = <:stone:900586388708290610>
cEmoji = <:coal:900586388708290610>
iEmoji = <:iron:900586388708290610>
gEmoji = <:gold:900586388708290610>
dEmoji = <:diamond:900586388708290610>
eEmoji = <:emerald:900586388708290610>
```

And the Console is Showing this

```
  File "main.py", line 33
    sEmoji = (<:stone:900586388708290610>)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what Syntax to Input there , Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do it put quotes around it. The `<` is being interpreted as a relational operator. Discord will "translate" the emoji for you.